# Cisco 9400-Supervisor Engine 1XL uplink help

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands

I have inherited a Cisco 9400 with 6 line cards installed. I am trying to use some ports on one of the cards. I noticed that there is no link activity lights, no indication of any activity.

I think this has something to do with the Supervisor engine. I looked up the documentation here
https://www.router-switch.com/media/upload/product-pdf/cisco-catalyst-9400-series-supervisor-engine-1xl-datasheet.pdf

And noticed that there are several options for "uplink" ports. I *think* this card is currently configured to support 4x10GbE, and 1x40GbE. I have no use for the 1x40GbE port, and would like to "turn on" the remaining 4x10GbE instead, giving me 8 of them.

I hope this helps, I do not know how to interpret it:

```
Switch#show module 
Chassis Type: C9410R              

Mod Ports Card Type                                   Model          Serial No.
---+-----+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------
1   48   48-Port UPOE 10/100/1000 (RJ-45)            C9400-LC-48U     xxxxxxxxxxx
2   48   48-Port UPOE 10/100/1000 (RJ-45)            C9400-LC-48U     xxxxxxxxxxx
3   24   24-Port 10 Gigabit Ethernet (SFP+)          C9400-LC-24XS    xxxxxxxxxxx
5   10   Supervisor 1 XL Module                      C9400-SUP-1XL    xxxxxxxxxxx
6   10   Supervisor 1 XL Module                      C9400-SUP-1XL    xxxxxxxxxxx
7   24   24-Port 10 Gigabit Ethernet (SFP+)          C9400-LC-24XS    xxxxxxxxxxx

Mod MAC addresses                    Hw   Fw           Sw                 Status
---+--------------------------------+----+------------+------------------+--------
1   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 1.1  16.10.2r[FC1] 16.11.01           ok        
2   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 1.1  16.10.2r[FC1] 16.11.01           ok        
3   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 1.0  16.10.2r[FC1] 16.11.01           ok        
5   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 2.0  16.10.2r[FC1] 16.11.01           ok        
6   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 2.0  16.10.2r[FC1] 16.11.01           ok        
7   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 1.0  16.10.2r[FC1] 16.11.01           ok        

Mod Redundancy Role     Operating Redundancy Mode Configured Redundancy Mode
---+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------
5   Active              sso                       sso                       
6   Standby             sso                       sso                       

Chassis MAC address range: 44 addresses from xxxx.xxxx.xxxx to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dual supervisors installed, you can only use the first four interfaces on the supervisors. You are limited to eight supervisor interfaces, either on one supervisor, or split between the two supervisors in a dual supervisor switch.

That is because only one supervisor is active at a time, and it can only control eight interfaces: four on each supervisor.

With only one supervisor, you can use the first four interfaces, and either the next four or the 40 Gb interface, but not both.